# memb.guild.roles.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I have a code where if someone joins the bot gives a Privat message and a Role but when a user joins, the bot does not give the message and the Role.

TypeError: memb.guild.roles.find

```
    const AUTOROLEID = "689098211536666624"

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (memb) => {

    var role = memb.guild.roles.find(r => r.id == "689098211536666624")

    if (role) {
        memb.addRole(role).then(() => {
            memb.send('', new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor(0x18FFFF).setDescription(`Willkommen aufm Discord deine aktuelle rolle ist ${role.name}!`))
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Discord.js v12 docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) you need to access the property `cache` after `<GuildMember>.guild.roles` which is a collection of all roles in the guild so you can try this:

```js
var role = memb.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == "689098211536666624")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the given code, I assume you are using discord.js v11 which got deprecated. So update to v12. v12 introduced the concept of managers/cache. In v11 you were able to use collection methods like `get()` and `find()`on collection structures, but now you need to ask for cache on a [manager](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache) before trying to use collection methods.

Eg:

```
var role = memb.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == "689098211536666624") //find requires a function
var var role = memb.guild.roles.cache.get("689098211536666624"); //get requires an ID as string.
```

and `<GuildMember>.addRole()` method got deprecated. You need to pass through the managers([GuildMemberRoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)) and then call then `.add()` method.

Eg:

```
var role = memb.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == "689098211536666624")
if(role){
  memb.roles.add(role).then(()=>{
   //do things.
  }
}
```